# Swift: Is there a Time only class available

Tags: swift

In java I use JODA's LocalTime class to set the hour, minute using `LocalTime(<hour>,<minute>)` . This will then be save in the database as integer using the `LocalTime.getMillisOfDay()` and when I get it from the database I convert it using the `LocalTime.fromMillisOfDay(<millis from the database>)`

Is there a class in Swift (I'm using 3.1) that do or can do this? Note that I don't need the "Date" only the hour and minute.

Comment: If you're always going to save and process it as "millis", what's wrong with `Int`?

Comment: during the runtime the app need the time in LocalTime type as it's being use for calculations not the millis so I have to convert it back to LocalTime from millis when I get it from the database.

Comment: User `Calendar` class from UIKit framework

Comment: If you're going to do time calculations, the tool is `DateComponents` (along with `Calendar`). There isn't really any other tool that's going to do accurate calculations. What are your expectations when there are DST transitions (spring forward, fall back)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a built-in class (pretty sure there is not...), but what's wrong with creating your own class (or struct):

```
struct LocalTime {
    var hours: Int
    var minutes: Int
    var seconds: Int

    init(hours: Int = 0, minutes: Int = 0, seconds: Int = 0) {
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds
    }

    func getMillisOfDay() -> Int {
        return ((((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60) + seconds) * 1000
    }

    mutating func from(millisOfDay milli: Int) {
        let sec = milli / 1000
        self.seconds = sec % 60
        let min = sec / 60
        self.minutes = min % 60
        self.hours = min / 60
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var t = LocalTime(hours: 10, minutes: 27, seconds: 12)
var millis = t.getMillisOfDay()
t.from(millisOfDay: millis)
```

Comment: A simple struct is nice if you just need to store "a nominal hour and minute." But when you start doing calculations like converting to milliseconds since midnight, you need to make decisions about how to deal with DST transitions. It's important to make those decisions explicitly (even if the decision is "I just want nominal values, not actual values"). It's easy to look at this and believe it's "milliseconds since midnight' when it actually isn't.

Comment: I ended up using somewhat like this. It's not the same as I don't have the "seconds" only hour and minute, but it does the same thing. I guess I'll have this mark as the answer then

Comment: I'm looking at the JodaTime class and this answer does NOT replace it. JodaTime takes the current time zone into account. I think this answer is buggy and wrong.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html

Answer (score 2):

This is from the Foundation documentation:

> "Date represents a single point in time."

This means that Date is the appropriate data type to use. The answer to your title question is 'No' because 'Date' gives you access to more than time - it can provide a calendar context. You can always use "unix" or "epoch" time. If you can use seconds instead of milliseconds these both return an elapsed time period in seconds:

```
    var sampleDate = Date()
    sampleDate.timeIntervalSince1970
    sampleDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
```